# Remove folder hierarchy from dependency during assembly:single goal

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I try to create a build for a product which is containing a tomcat. The tomcat folder structure should be at the root of the assembled zip file. But actually I have one folder hierarchy too much.

My `pom.xml`:

```
...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.3</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

...

<build>     
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>                       
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

...
```

And the `src/assembly/bin.xml`:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

  <id>bin</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>      
  </formats>

  <dependencySets>      
      <dependencySet>                               
          <includes>
             <include>org.apache.tomcat:tomcat:zip</include>
          </includes>
          <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
          <unpack>true</unpack>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

The structure of the referenced zip is this:

```
apache-tomcat-8.5.3
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── RELEASE-NOTES
├── RUNNING.txt
├── bin
├── conf
├── lib
├── logs
├── temp
├── webapps
└── work
```

My result (`bin.zip`) should look like this:

```
bin
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── RELEASE-NOTES
├── RUNNING.txt
├── bin
├── conf
├── lib
├── logs
├── temp
├── webapps
└── work
```

But actually it looks like this:

```
bin
└─ apache-tomcat-8.5.3
   ├── LICENSE
   ├── NOTICE
   ├── RELEASE-NOTES
   ├── RUNNING.txt
   ├── bin
   ├── conf
   ├── lib
   ├── logs
   ├── temp
   ├── webapps
   └── work
```

And finally my question:

**How I can remove the `apache-tomcat-8.5.3` folder during the `assembly:single` goal?**

The tomcat dependency is only an example. I have many more cases.

Comment: Can you post your whole `bin.xml`?

Comment: Done. But I only leave the boiler plate xml out.